# Python client / server question

Tags: python, sockets, client, command

I'm working on a bit of a project in python. I have a client and a server. The server listens for connections and once a connection is received it waits for input from the client. The idea is that the client can connect to the server and execute system commands such as ls and cat. This is my server code:

```
import sys, os, socket


host = ''                
port = 50105

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
print("Server started on port: ", port)

s.listen(5)
print("Server listening\n")
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'New connection from ', addr
while (1):
    rc = conn.recv(5)
    pipe = os.popen(rc)
    rl = pipe.readlines()
    file = conn.makefile('w', 0)
    file.writelines(rl[:-1])
    file.close()
    conn.close()
```

And this is my client code:

```
import sys, socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'localhost'
port = input('Port: ')
s.connect((host, port))
cmd = raw_input('$ ')
s.send(cmd) 
file = s.makefile('r', 0)
sys.stdout.writelines(file.readlines())
```

When I start the server I get the right output, saying the server is listening. But when I connect with my client and type a command the server exits with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "server.py", line 21, in <module>
  rc = conn.recv(2)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 165, in _dummy
  raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

On the client side, I get the output of ls but the server gets screwed up.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I make it so the client will stay open for more commands to be inputed. So that the client can keep inputting commands and they're executed on the server.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing ssh, why?

Comment: It's not really reinventing SSH its just a basic server client program where the client can remotely execute commands. Not on level of security SSH provides though. Just simple. Kinda like telnet.

Comment: If you really want to learn about this, get the book "Advanced Programming in a Unix Environment" second edition... It will explain *everything* you need to get moving on client/server programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Server and client problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703187/python-server-and-client-problems)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code calls `conn.close()` and then loops back around to `conn.recv()`, but `conn` is already closed.

Comment: I took conn.close() out of the server and now when I type a command in the client it just hangs. Nothing happens.

Comment: In that case, your `file.readlines()` in the client is waiting for the server to send something more (because it might). You'll have to decide - do you want your server to accept one command and then close the connection, or do you want the server to send something that indicates the command output has completed? If the latter, what would you like to send?

Comment: Well I want the server to send something that indicates the command output has completed. The idea is that the server stays listening for connections and the client can enter a command, get the output of it, then enter more commands if the user wishes.

Comment: There are two alternatives - the server *can* stay listening for new connections, even if each individual connection is closed after the command has completed (this is sort of like how simple HTTP works). This has the advantage of being much simpler to code. The alternative is to have the connection between the client and server stay connected for multiple commands, but you'll have to choose some way of marking the end of server command output so the client knows when to show the next prompt. The trick is choosing something that isn't going to show up in command output itself.

Comment: As a third option, you could have the *server* generate the prompt when it's done executing the command. Then the client becomes very simple, and just passes characters back and forth. In fact, at that point you're well on your way to reinventing [telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet).

Comment: Hm that third option seems the best. And the most simple lol. How exactly could I do this? Would I have the server have the raw_input()? I'm a bit confused as to how I would accomplish this.

Comment: Your server can read bytes from the `conn` socket, accumulating them in a string, until it sees a Return character `\r`. This is essentially what `raw_input()` does with the terminal, and although there might be a way to connect `raw_input()` to a socket, you're probably best off just reading from the socket yourself. When you get a complete command, run it and write the output to the socket. You can use the `telnet` command as a client.

Comment: I see. So I would just have the server wait for a command and then execute it until it sees a return character?

Comment: That's right. Give it a go, and perhaps make a new question if you're having trouble, as this comment thread is getting a bit long. :)

Comment: Yea it has lol. I just don't really know how exactly I'd do this as I'm not very good at python(still learning). I'll give it a go though and see what I can come up with

Answer (score 3):

If you want your client to repeat what it's doing, just add a loop in there ;)

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'localhost'
port = input('Port: ')
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    cmd = raw_input('$ ')
    s.send(cmd) 
    file = s.makefile('r', 0)
    sys.stdout.writelines(file.readlines())
```

Should probably be closer to what you want.

Other comments:

```
s.listen(1)
```

This statement should probably be moved outside of the while loop. You only need to call `listen` once.

```
pipe = os.popen(rc)
```

os.popen has been deprecated, use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead.

```
file = s.makefile('r', 0)
```

You're opening a file, yet you never close the file. You should probably add a `file.close()` after your `sys.stdout.writelines()` call.

**EDIT:** to answer below comment; done here due to length and formatting

As it stands, you read from the socket once, and then immediately close it. Thus, when the client goes to send the next command, it sees that the server closed the socket and indicates an error.

The solution is to change your server code so that it can handle receiving multiple commands. Note that this is solved by introducing another loop.

You need to wrap

```
rc = conn.recv(2)
pipe = os.popen(rc)
rl = pipe.readlines()
fl = conn.makefile('w', 0)
fl.writelines(rl[:-1])
```

in another `while True:` loop so that it repeats until the client disconnects, and then wrap that in a try-except block that catches the IOError that is thrown by conn.recv() when the client disconnects.

the try-except block should look like

```
try:
    # the described above loop goes here
except IOError:
    conn.close()
# execution continues on...
```

Comment: Well the loop works great as once a command is entered, it's executed on the server machine, I get the output on my client machine and then I get the '$' prompt again. The thing is, after that when I type another command nothing happens. Then if I try another command I get an error socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Hm interesting. Now the client just hangs and I don't get the output of the command until the server is closed.

Comment: Changing `fl = conn.makefile('w', 0)` to `fl = conn.makefile('w')` fixed it for me. Setting the second argument, which is a buffer size, to 0 seemed to not work out that well.

Comment: I also had to add `if len(rc) == 0: raise IOError` after `rc = conn.recv(2)` because for me, when recv was called on a socket that was closed on the other end, it just returned nothing. I _thought_ that it should raise an IOError, but I guess it doesn't?

(If someone else could jump in here and explain why, it'd be appreciated.)

Comment: Alright I've done everything suggested and I'm still getting the same exact problem -_- It still hangs until the server is closed. Just to make sure heres my server/client: http://pastie.org/1447201

Comment: The `while True` in the server needs to be _inside_ the try-except block. You have it the other way around.

Comment: Still not working. It's still hanging :/ it seems to not like me. http://pastie.org/1450029 I'm pretty sure I wrapped the while True correctly...

Comment: What version of python are you running? Maybe it's something with my client?

Comment: I'm on 2.7.1, but the socket code hasn't changed for a long time as far as I know. I'm using the client that's in my answer.

Comment: I'm on 2.6.5 and I'm running the server and client I put in the pastie. It's still not working though :/

Comment: Can you pastie the stack backtrace that is shown when you press ctrl-c in the server?

Comment: hrm. yeah, I can't help you anymore. I suggest using the good 'ol `print()` everything method of debugging now.