# Python server / client remote execute problem

Tags: python, sockets, client

I'm working on a project in Python that I'm having trouble with. I've asked so many people but they seem to not be able to help me :/ I'm coding a little program that executes system commands. The idea is that one machine opens the server and the other one opens the client and connects to the IP / Port. From there they can execute system commands and obtain the output. Only problem is, whenever I run the server it opens successfully then when I open the client and connect to the server I get the shell but when I type a command it just hangs until the server is closed then I get the output of the command on the client.

Server.py:

```
import sys, os, socket
```

host = ''
port = 50105
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
print("Server started on port: ", port)
s.listen(1)
while (1):
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'New connection from ', addr
    try:
        while True:
            rc = conn.recv(2)
            pipe = os.popen(rc)
            rl = pipe.readlines()
            fl = conn.makefile('w')
            fl.writelines(rl[:-1])
            fl.close()
    except IOError:
            conn.close()

Client.py:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'localhost'
port = input('Port: ')
s.connect((host, port))
while (1):
    cmd = raw_input('$ ')
    s.send(cmd) 
    file = s.makefile('r', 0)
    sys.stdout.writelines(file.readlines())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    file.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried based on [your](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642345/python-client-server-question) [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642795/python-client-and-server) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703187/python-server-and-client-problems) on this topic? Your code looks largely similar to what you've posted before, and there are lots of answers suggesting different things to try.

Comment: I've tried many of them and none seem to work.

Comment: In the client, I would pull the makefile out of the loop and make sure you flush what is sent -- I think you probably want to do something similar on the server making sure you're flushing where you expect the two to communicate...

Comment: I did that for both but it still fixes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I told you exactly what the problem was in this answer to your previous question:

[Python - Server and client problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703187/python-server-and-client-problems)

I'm not joking or anything, I tried your code, I figured out what the problem was, and I told you how to fix it.

Once again, with emphasis:

When you makefile() on the socket and then use readlines() on it, readlines() will continue to read lines until you reach an end of file, which in the socket case when it is closed from the other end. **Therefore you do not get any output until the connection is closed, as readlines() will not stop reading lines until the connection is closed.**

Neither readlines() nor makefile() in this case makes no sense to me, especially since you create it and close it after each command. Just use send() and recv() on both ends.

You probably also want to have some sort of actual "protocol" so the server tells the client "HERE COMES A RESPONSE" and "THIS IS THE END OF THE RESPONSE" so that the client knows. Otherwise it gets hard to know when to stop waiting for more response. :)

Comment: I know but this makes no sense to me. I'm new with Python sockets and I don't really know how to work them. I've tried taking out the code in the while true: statement in the server and replaced it with s.recv(1024) and then s.send(1024) but it won't work as I get a broken pipe. Could you please explain how I would do this to a noob?

Comment: @AustinM: First of all, you could have said that you didn't understand it in the last question. Please delete this duplicate. Second of all: You start with removing all makefiles and readlines and writelines, and then you try to do what you want only with send() and recv(). You'll learn a lot by doing that. You need to understand what you are doing, and if I write your code, you won't do that.

Comment: I wasn't asking you to write my code, I was asking to elaborate with what I would do with send() and recv(). Right now I'm just playing around with them seeing what I can do but no luck. I've tried declaring cmd as the s.recv() then executing it with os.system() and sending it but also no luck.

Comment: @AustinM: You *send* with send() and *recieve* with recv(). Very simple. "I've tried declaring cmd as the s.recv()" I have no idea what you are trying to say here, that sentence make no sence.